# AuthenticationManager.Login desn't work with specified user

Tags: authentication, sitecore, sitecore8.1

I want to login a user via *AuthenticationManager.Login(user)*, but when I check that user via *AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser()*, I get the *"extranet\Anonymous"* user. However, when I try to login a virtual user I created before, it works.

My code:

```
Log.Info(string.Format("Trying to login with unique key '{0}'...", uniqueKey), item);
User user = FindDocCheckUserByUniqueKey(uniqueKey);
Log.Info(string.Format("User found by unique key '{0}': {1}", uniqueKey, user != null ? user.Name : "null"), item);
AuthenticationManager.Login((user != null ? user : BuildDocCheckUser()).Name); // login user found by unique key or the virtual user
user = AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
Log.Info(string.Format("Active user: {0}", user != null ? user.Name : "null"), item);
Log.Info(string.Format("Active user is authenticated: {0}", user != null && user.IsAuthenticated), item);
```

The log output for the real user (which doesn't work):

```
3640 13:23:30 INFO  Trying to login with unique key '596e2c332f6b0f34241039ec8ce9c18d'...
3640 13:23:30 INFO  User found by unique key '596e2c332f6b0f34241039ec8ce9c18d': extranet\dc_596e2c332f6b0f34241039ec8ce9c18d
3640 13:23:30 INFO  Active user: extranet\Anonymous
3640 13:23:30 INFO  Active user is authenticated: False
```

The log output for the virtual user (which works):

```
3560 13:22:48 INFO  Trying to login with unique key '395f625038a3293fe1f10eff84529556'...
3560 13:22:48 INFO  User found by unique key '395f625038a3293fe1f10eff84529556': null
3560 13:22:48 INFO  Active user: extranet\DocCheck User
3560 13:22:48 INFO  Active user is authenticated: True
```

Is there a way to force the user to be logged in?

Comment: can you try to add a second parameter to this method AuthenticationManager.Login(user, true);this is the method from the AuthenticationManager class:  public static bool Login(string userName, bool persistent)

Comment: This doesn't work. Same effect. :-(

Comment: Can you check FindDocCheckUserByUniqueKey(uniqueKey) why the user is null? what is unique id for the user?

Comment: FindDocCheckUserByUniqueKey(uniqueKey) finds a user with the user name dc_<uniqueKey> and checks if it is in a special role. If not found or not in that role, this method returns null.

Comment: I just found a strange thing: All the real users are imported from another sitecore instance via a package. These users couldn't be logged in. If I create a real user on that sitecore instance, the user **can** be logged in. So is there a difference between an imported user and a newly created one?

Comment: Can be password  that is not serialezed. Can you try to reset password of an imported user? and try to login in again

Comment: Solution found! The imported users are disabled by default. Enabling them makes the login process work. – Thank you @SitecoreClimber for giving me the password hint so I took a closer look in the sitecore user manager. :-)

Comment: @SitecoreClimber: You should post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted. Nice job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a second parameter for login method

```
AuthenticationManager.Login(user, true);
```

Also you need to check the password,because password are not serialized when user is imported.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found! The imported users are disabled by default. Enabling them makes the login process work. – Thank you @SitecoreClimber for giving me the password hint so I took a closer look in the sitecore user manager. :-)